Disabling Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy/Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy to gain SharedArrayBuffer access while debugging
Using Windows 11 and the latest Chrome version, I am unable to make use of SharedArrayBuffer. I get the following error:
ReferenceError: SharedArrayBuffer is not defined.

My web page is served through http://localhost:55000. I'm using the built-in web server provided by VS code when debugging Flutter web apps.
The page web I am debugging does have window.isSecureContext == true, I verified.
I tried adding --disable-web-security then --disable-web-security --user-data-dir=C:\somefolder, but Chrome tells me --disable-web-security is not a recognized option. I guess this option is now deprecated?
How can I either

completely disable web security in Chrome while debugging?
instruct the Flutter VS code web server to add response headers when serving .js files?

